# Compiling node.js on 32-bit system

Tags: node.js, 32bit-64bit, v8

I need to compile node.js on a 32-bit system to be compatible with code I already have.

I started with the source code from nodejs.org and compiled it.  Then I began by changing lines 164-166 in the common.gypi file.  It was:

```
164           [ 'target_arch=="x64"', {
165             'cflags': [ '-m64' ],
166             'ldflags': [ '-m64' ],
167           }],
```

and now it is:

```
164           [ 'target_arch=="x64"', {
165             'cflags': [ '-m32' ],
166             'ldflags': [ '-m32' ],
167           }],
```

When I tried to make it again, I am getting these errors:

../deps/v8/src/execution.h:259: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
../deps/v8/src/execution.h:260: error: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
../deps/v8/src/execution.h:259: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
../deps/v8/src/execution.h:260: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

These errors are referring to these lines:

```
#ifdef V8_TARGET_ARCH_X64
  static const uintptr_t kInterruptLimit = V8_UINT64_C(0xfffffffffffffffe);
  static const uintptr_t kIllegalLimit = V8_UINT64_C(0xfffffffffffffff8);
```

I believe this code is from google's v8 source code.

I would appreciate any suggestions on either how to fix these particular compiling errors and/or how to compile the 64-bit node.js on a 32-bit system.  Most the the research I've done is how to compile something 32-bit for a 64-bit system.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are on x86_32, and want to generate an x86_64 version of node? Why don't you simply compile an x86_32 bit node.js?

Comment: @phihag

Could you please point me to where I can find a x86_32 node.js?  I tried googling it and looking through the nodejs.org and came to these other release files: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.5/ but it doesn't specify if its for 32bit.  

My boss put me on this task so he probably had a purpose in having me download the current sourcecode.  I will find out if the x86_32 bit is allowed.

Thanks for replying!

Comment: Added an answer that describes how to compile node for x86_32. Note that setting up a cross-compiling infrastructure can be quite complicated. Feel free to ask a new question and/or post a comment on my answer if you run into any trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to build an x86_32 version of node, you are modifying the parameters for the wrong target architecture. Instead, give the `--dest-cpu` parameter to the configure script, like this:

```sh
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure --prefix /usr/local --dest-cpu ia32
make
```

If these commands finish successfully, there should be a working x86_32 binary in `./out/Release/node`:

```sh
~/node$ file -b ./out/Release/node
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked
(uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, (...), not stripped
~/node$ ./out/Release/node
> 1 + 1
2
```

You can install it in your running system (at the prefix that you specified in the `--prefix` parameter above) with `sudo make install`.

Note that this requires a working C and C++ compiler to be set up. On Debian/Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install build-essential` (or `build-essential:i386` if you're cross-compiling) should get you started. On rpm-based distributions, try `sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"`.

Comment: May I ask, is there a difference between the code here  at github.com/joyent/node.git and the current 64-bit source code at nodejs.org.

Also, when I try to sudo make install, I encounter this error: <br>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'deps/uv/include/ares.h'
Can you reiterate what you mean by (at the prefix that you specified in the --prefix parameter above)?

Lastly, can you please explain why we need /usr/local ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It should work fine either with git or the (architecture-independent) source tarball (but I only tested it with the git version). Check that `ares.h` is present. It seems to have been moved recently; do you get the error with [this tarball](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.6/node-v0.8.6.tar.gz) as well as the git version? `--prefix /usr/local` means that the node.js binary will be installed as `/usr/local/bin/node` when you run `sudo make install`. You can pick another directory if you want, but `/usr/local` is the one suggested by [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Just to let you know, ares.h was not present in the git version but it was present in the source tarbell.  I am done with this task because of your help.  Thank you!  I am researching into finding the best sqlite module to go with node.js now.  Comparing between these: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-db-sqlite